# How the OS ensure security?

Tags: c, linux, windows, operating-system, kernel

In the most low-level layer (0's and 1's) how the operating system ensure security? When you open an app the app instructions goes directly to the processor and the instructions are executed. How the OS interacts with the software for ensuring security?

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: "Security" can mean a billion very different thing. Which security features are you talking about specifically?

Comment: How would an OS decide when to deny access to a file? How can the OS know it's *you* asking access -- or at least software started by you, or (deeper yet) software started *by* software started by you? What if the software you started is a Trojan?

Answer (score 1):

In modern platforms, it's basically about **execution modes** on the processors. That's it: there are some instructions than can only be run in **RING 0**, and the kernel itself is the only process allowed to run in this mode. Take a look at [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes) [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29) WIKI entries.